# Is it the correct coding convention to use different packages for different functions in Android?

Tags: java, android, coding-style

com.example.appname is going to be used for the app functionality.
com.example.login is going to be used for the user registration,login,verification etc.
com.example.processes is going to be used for activities that run in the back ground like SMSReceiver etc.

Is this the correct way to program in Android?

Comment: that depends on how you feel comfortable and what are you office standards . Main reason for adding packages is to make project structure clean and easily understandable to everyone. You should use meaningful name everywhere i.e. for packages, variables, classes etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no 'correct' way of packaging in Android development, It mainly depends on your convenience. What i do usually (when working with a team) is try to mimic MVC structure as much as possible, The team agree upon a structure like below and start coding in that style like:

1. Package for Models(POJO classes)
2. Package for Views

   1. I usually add Activities and Fragments also inside sub packages of Views
   2. Custom Views packages
3. Package for Controllers

   1. Sub package for BroadcastRecivers
   2. Content providers,Services etc
4. Package for Boiler Plate code

To see another approach for your problem refer [this blog](http://blog.smartlogic.io/2013/07/09/organizing-your-android-development-code-structure)